# Filter boolean value in java8

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have a problem in writing the following code where I want to filter a part based on a boolean value at one of  the properties.
But I am getting error when I am trying to write that

The object I am trying to check before adding it to the database is the active flag of esn.
But I am getting compilation error.
What I am doing wrong

The object which I am trying to filter is

```
unarchiveParts:::::[Part(partId=20001582, partNumber=2411M39P02, partDescription=BEARING, NO 3 BALL, esn=Esn(esnId=2233, name=892292, active=true, workOrder=WorkOrder(workOrderId=2313, number=000010149107, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), gate=Gate(gateId=1, name=Gate 0, active=true, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), model=Model(modelId=48, name=CFM56-7, label=CFM56-7, engineFamily=EngineFamily(engineFamilyId=13, name=CFM56, label=CFM56, site=com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Site@75bb5a71, otrOffset=0, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), customer=com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Customer@6c348019, isQpEngine=true, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation), workScope=WorkScope(workScopeId=0, name=Unknown, ooa_label=UNK), visitIndex=0), quantity=1/1, status=Status(statusId=0, name=N/A, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), materialStream=MaterialStream(materialStreamId=2, name=Used, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), source=Source(sourceId=24, name=Celma, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation)), oem=null, poNumber=N/A, manualCsoCommit=null, autoCsoCommit=null, drStatus=null, airwayBill=null, coreMaterial=true, active=true, tenant=Tenant(tenantId=1, name=GE Aviation), module=null, hpcStatus=null, actionUsers=[], shipOut=null, receipt=null, critShip=false, lateCall=false, exEsn=null, accumOffset=0, poLineNum=00000)]
```

For which I have written which is giving compilation error is

```
public void unarchiveParts(final List<Integer> partIDs) {       
        List<Part> parts = partRepo.findAll((root, query, builder) -> root.get("partId").in(partIDs));
        log.debug("unarchiveParts:::::"+ parts.toString());
        parts.stream().filter(e -> e.getEsn().getActive() == Boolean.TRUE)
             .forEach(p -> p.setActive(true));
        partRepo.saveAll(parts);
    }
```

Comment: `List` does not have a `filter` method. Did you mean `parts.stream().filter...`?

Comment: Sorry..yes..but how to filter for a boolean value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface List doesn't have a method filter. I think you want to do it:

```
public void unarchiveParts(final List<Integer> partIDs) {       
        List<Part> parts = partRepo.findAll((root, query, builder) -> root.get("partId").in(partIDs));
        log.debug("unarchiveParts:::::"+ parts.toString());
        parts.stream()
             .filter(e -> e.getEsn.getActive)
             .forEach(p -> p.setActive(true));
        partRepo.saveAll(parts);
    }
```

Comment: Yes.. sorry my mistake..but how to filter for boolean value of esn in the object

Comment: I writed it. .filter() resieve boolean, your e.getEsn.getActive is boolean

Comment: Ok .will try and let u know.. thnx